# Ngrx store immutable state with an array?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I'm planning to create a large application with Angular 5. I want to use Ngrx too to store the state of my app. But there is one thing I don't understand.

Let's say that I have an object (I don't use classes or interfaces now for simplicity), that represents my state in a `Store`:

```
let state = {
    x: 10,
    y: [1, 2, 3]
};
```

In every article that I read the writers are using `Object.assign()` to create a copy of the state in a reducer. For example:

```
...
case SET_X:
    return Object.assign({}, state, {x: 123});
...
```

But this doesn't create a deep copy of the state. So the `y` array of the new state is the same as the old one's. This is against the concept of Redux/Ngrx, I think.

So does this mean that I have to use `List` Immutable.js or something like that for example, and every article is "wrong"? Or am I missing something? I don't think that this would be a very special case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No you don't have to use Immutable.js (and I wouldn't recommend you to).

If you want to update the array, let say add a value, you should just do it like that:

```
const state = {
  x: 10,
  y: [1, 2, 3]
};

const newState = {
  ...state,
  y: [...state.y, 4]
}
```

Here you can notice 2 things:
 - Instead of using Object.assign, you can use the spread operator with object
 - To keep the immutability with an Array, you have to create a new reference. And you can also just use the spread operator on an Array and then just add a new value for example. If you wanted to add it before and not after: `y: [4, ...state.y]`, if you wanted to remove all the `3` in the array: `y: state.y.filter(nb => nb !== 3)`

Comment: Thank you. And when I'm changing the `x` and not the array itself (`y`), then I don't have to deal with the array's immutability (because the new and the old `y` are the same)?

Comment: Exactly. If you want to only change `x` just do `const newState = {
  ...state,
  x: 100
}`

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Comment: @RolandRácz Does this implementation trigger state change event ?, In my case it's not triggering state change event , I added new element to array it does not recognise change.

Comment: Did you create a new reference for the array or did you use push? If you don't create a new reference that'd be your issue